# Use ENUM to default value to ineligible

Tags: java, enums, java-8

I have following code that handles `EligibilityType`:

```
public enum EligibilityType {

    E (EligibilityTypeEnum.ELIGIBLE),
    I (EligibilityTypeEnum.INELIGIBLE);

    private final EligibilityTypeEnum eligibilityTypeEnum;

    private EligibilityType(EligibilityTypeEnum eligibilityTypeEnum) {
        this.eligibilityTypeEnum = eligibilityTypeEnum;
    }

    public EligibilityTypeEnum toEligibilityTypeEnum() {
        return eligibilityTypeEnum;
    }
}
```

I learned that everything that is not of value "E" should be set to `EligibilityTypeEnum.INELIGIBLE`.

And this is how I am calling it:

```
...
List<Workout> workouts = workoutResults.getWorkout();
for(int i = 0; i< workouts.size(); ++i) {
    ...
    stin.getWorkouts().get(i).setEligibilityType(EligibilityType.valueOf(workouts.get(i).getRecommendation()).toEligibilityTypeEnum());
    ...
}
```

Right now the code blows up if `workouts.get(i).getRecommendation()` returns "C".

Does anyone see any other way of achieving this except `try-catch`?

Is there a way to set a default value in enum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can have in `EligibilityType` a map with all possible values

```
public static final Map<String, EligibilityType> ALL_MAP = Arrays.stream(values())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Enum::toString, Function.identity()));
```

then you can handle gracefully the default case

```
EligibilityType.ALL_MAP.getOrDefault(someString, EligibilityType.DEFAULT)
```